# How to remove previous marker when adding new marker

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to remove previous marker when adding  new marker in the  onMapReady . can anyone help me out from this problem. this is my code...

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
    
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Test");
    
            ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
                    Double f_latitude = snapshot.child("f_latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double f_longitude = snapshot.child("f_longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(f_latitude, f_longitude);
                    
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("ELE00001").icon(bitmapDescriptorFactory(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ele_marker)));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST);
                return;
            }
    
        }
```

*How to remove previous marker when adding  new marker in the  onMapReady . can anyone help me out from this problem. this is my code...*

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that. You can clear all your map or just remove the current marker before adding it.

To clear whole map, you can use the below code:

```java
mMap.clear();
```

To remove only previous marker, you should define a variable which stores the current marker.
Firstly, define a `Marker` object in your class.

```java
Marker currentMarker;
```

Then you need to make sure that, if previous marker is already exist, you need to remove it before adding new one, and update your variable with the new marker.

```java
@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Test");

    ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (currentMarker != null) {
                currentMarker.remove();
            }
            Double f_latitude = snapshot.child("f_latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            Double f_longitude = snapshot.child("f_longitude").getValue(Double.class);

            LatLng location = new LatLng(f_latitude, f_longitude);

            currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("ELE00001").icon(bitmapDescriptorFactory(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ele_marker)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
        return;
    }

}
```

This code will remove previous marker if it exist,

```java
if (currentMarker != null) {
    currentMarker.remove();
}
```

And this code will help you to store new added marker.

```java
currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("ELE00001").icon(bitmapDescriptorFactory(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ele_marker)));
```